# Track progress of facebook graph api requests

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, promise, progress

I am willing to track the progress of the querying from Facebook's graph api. I have this promise in an angular service

```
getPosts: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        FB.api(
            "/me/home", {since:'yesterday','limit': limit},
            function ( response ) {
                if ( response && !response.error ) {

                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;  
    },
```

and in my controller I use `FBS.getPosts().then(function (data) {...});` . I am willing to be able to keep track of the progress of this promise and be able to display it on my page. Any ideas if this is even possible? I tried adding `function (progress)` , after the error function of the promise in my controller, had no luck though. Somewhere I read you can use `.progress(function (progress){...})` like the `.then` one but it didn't work.

Comment: How would you do it without promises? The underlying service (facebook) would have to support it in order for you to use it.

Comment: Also `.progress` is a broken API and you should probably not use it. It will likely be removed at a future point, and other bigger promise libraries like Bluebird and Q are already removing it.

Comment: I don't want to do it without promises, I never said so. I am using Q for my promises and asked, if someone knows how to use this together with facebook graph api to track the progress. Right now I am getting loads of posts at a time, which surely slows down my app and I want to show the user that everything is ok and the app isn't stuck at one place

Comment: I asked, how would you do it without promises, not asking you to do it without promises. Facebook does not expose that functionality, if you want you can track the progress of multiple requests (that is, how many out of N requests are done) but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. That means, in a few words - Facebook graph api does not offer any track of query progress, right?

Comment: Correct, this is exactly what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>I don't like leaving questions in the [promise](/questions/tagged/promise) tag open as I've made is a personal goal to keep it clean :) so here goes:</sup>

Facebook does not expose that functionality, if you want you can track the progress of multiple requests (that is, how many out of N requests are done) but that's not the same thing.

What you are asking for is simply put - impossible. There is no way to know how far the query has progressed without Facebook telling you, and they're not telling you.

Happy coding.